# Ionic disable back and home button hardware in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I am creating an app in ionic, user must fill survey after 3 hours. I want to disable back and home button when survey screen is enable. I know we can do this with back button in android using this plugin:

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
// do something here
});
```

I want to know is there any plugin that disable the home button for IOS? If yes, please let me know the plugin. If no, please share with me documentation which apple describe to restrict this functionality. Thank you

Comment: What version of ionic?

Comment: version 5 we are using

Comment: I don't think there will be any API exposed by Apple which disables the home button from an App. It's a big problem for the end user right, where user who is the owner of the device does not have the privilege to switch between apps.

Comment: Can you share with me any documentation in which apple says that? So i can show to client and tell him it's not possible